# Script works for windows 10 but not for windows 7

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$CenterScreen = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;

$BucketPath = '\\**\bucket'#Path to the available programs for user
$BucketDBPath = '\\**B$'
#$BucketDBPath = "\\**\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt"#Path to write the Txt file
$PdfPath = '\\srv\s$\installer\pdf'

$img = [Drawing.Image]::FromFile('\\s**\bg.png')



Function Install(){#Write txt file with %hostname% and list of programs
    if (Test-Path $BucketDBPath\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt ) { Remove-Item $BucketDBPath\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt }
        ForEach ($item in $listBox1.SelectedItems) {
            if (Test-Path $PdfPath\$item.pdf){Start-Process ((Resolve-Path "$pdfPath\$item.pdf").path)}
           # "$item.exe" | Out-File $BucketDBPath\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt 
            echo "$item.exe" >> $BucketDBPath\$env:COMPUTERNAME.txt 
               }
              $form.close()}

Function MakeForm(){
$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '650,420'
$Form.text                       = "Installer"
$Form.TopMost                    = $true
$form.BackgroundImage            = $img
$form.BackgroundImageLayout      = 'Tile'
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = 'FixedDialog'
$Form.TopMost = $true
$form.StartPosition = $CenterScreen

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "Welcome!`r`nChoose program\s you wish to install"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 10
$label1.BackColor                = "White"
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,10)
$Label1.Font                     = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',15,[System.Drawing.FontStyle]([System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold))


$ListBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.ListBox
$ListBox1.width                  = 431
$ListBox1.height                 = 280
@($programlist) | ForEach-Object {[void] $ListBox1.Items.Add($_)}
$listbox1.Font                   = 'Microsoft Sans Serif,12'
$ListBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(201,60)
$listbox1.SelectionMode          = 'MultiExtended'
$listbox1.BackColor              = "#cdedfc"

$Button3                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button3.BackColor               = "#caebfc"
$Button3.width                   = 100
$Button3.text                     = "Install"
$Button3.Font                    = New-Object System.Drawing.Font('Microsoft Sans Serif',12)
$Button3.height                  = 30
$Button3.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(530,370)


$Form.controls.AddRange(@($ListBox1,$Button3,$Label1))
$Button3.Add_Click({ Install })
[void]$form.ShowDialog()}

$data = gci $BucketPath | %{$_.BaseName}

$programlist = $data

MakeForm
```

Which is a pretty simple script, it shows the user a nice gui of files in a shared network path, he can tag them and a txt file will be created with his hostname on other network path with his selections.

Ive compiled it to EXE. works great for windows 10 users. but when i run this exe for windows 7 users it does nothing.
Can anyone spot the problem?

*edit
Compiled it with ps2exe gui from Markus Scholtes in the official technet.microsoft site

Comment: _Ive compiled it to EXE._ --> Could you please [edit] your question and add some detail how you did this?

Comment: If you run the script as-is without exe conversion, does it work in Win7?